# Asp.net MVC Session termina

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, session

Tenho uma aplicação *ASP.NET MVC 4.0* em um servidor da **KingHost**. No meu `web.config` eu faço o seguinte:

```
<sessionState timeout="1000"></sessionState>  
   <authentication mode="Forms">     
       <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="1000" >
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

**No meu controller de login:**

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( agent.IDAgente.ToString() , false );
```

***Obs:*** **Não estou usando MemberShip Provider**

**O que acontece:**

Mesmo configurando o `timeout` para ***1000*** (quase um dia) após 2 minutos de navegação a sessão cai. O que uso para buscar dados da sessão é: `HttpContext.Current.Session["variavel"]`.

***O que pode estar causando isso?***

Comment: Só uma dúvida, você perde sessão durante o teste? Faz modificações no código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já fazem dois anos, penei muito para descobrir que uso asp.net mvc4 (asp.net 4.5) mas o servidor da KingHost está configurado para rodar com asp.net 3.5.

Resumindo, .net 4.5 consome o dobro de memória que o .net 3.5. Se o servidor não estiver configurado para ceder essa memória para a aplicação, ele simplesmente *"derruba"* as sessões ativas para liberar memória.

Isso é uma coisa que nem a equipe da KingHost soube me responder, já que eles são peritos em PHP mas querem oferecer .net.

Uma pena. Mas muito obrigado @user6026 e @Spectron

Answer (score 0):

Coloque no seu ***timeout="30"*** que é 30 minutos, pela [**Referência do Site MSDN Microsoft**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) diz que: 
***"O Timeout propriedade não pode ser definida como um valor maior do que 525,600 minutos (1 ano). O valor padrão é 20 minutos."***, deve ser isso o problema, porque, você ultrapassou o máximo permitido que é ***525,600***. Só lembrando que o valor é em minutos.

*Referencia*

- [Propriedade HttpSessionState.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Desculpe não entendi. Eu coloquei um dia (1000) e vc está dizendo que ultrapassei o limite de um ano. (525600)

Comment: @Ozory eu coloquei `525,600 quinhentos e vinte e cinco e seiscentos`

Comment: Desculpe agora entendi...vou fazer o ajuste e testar

Comment: user6026 obrigado pela dica, mas mesmo assim ainda nao funciona. Ja nao sei mais o que pode ser.... : /

Comment: O correto é 525.600 minutos mesmo, que dividido por 60 e depois por 24 resulta em 365 dias. 525 minutos não equivale a um ano

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se no servidor da KingHost não tem alguma configuração de timeout.

> Isso do tempo das sessões pode estar relacionado com o servidor e o iis, eu já tive um site num servidor partilhado onde as sessões
>   estoiravam em 5 minutos ou menos, eles tinham x memória disponível
>   para cada site, quando atingisse essa memória o próprio iis faz um
>   "recycle" à pool que o site está associado e limpa as sessões todas,
>   depois mudei o site para uma vps e nunca mais tive problema.
>
> Tem que ver se o seu site não está consumindo muita memória também,
>   pois na vps cheguei a ter um site que estava a consumir muita
>   memória(não testava uns dados que vinham com get e dava erro no
>   script, gastando muita memória ao server), e depois de tratado o
>   problema ficou bom.

fonte:http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/460500-sessiontimeout-nao-funciona/